# How to find downloaded files location

Tags: firefox, download

I downloaded a file from Mega.co.nz, and when it finished downloading I closed the open file command, and now I cannot find the downloaded file.

I use Firefox to access the download link.

So, what is the location of the downloaded file?

Comment: I wasn't able to find it too in Download folder, it was in Desktop.

Answer (score 9):

The site has nothing to do with this. The file has been downloaded to a (default) pre-set location, or wherever you have told Firefox to store it in a prompt.

First try opening your downloads: Firefox Button > Downloads (pops up). In here should be a list of all your downloads.

If this doesn't work:

You can find your pre-set download location here:
Firefox Button > Options (pops up) > General Tab.

In this tab, there's a section "Downloads" where two options are displayed: 
(1) Save files in 
(2) Always ask where to store files.

In case (1), check this folder. In case (2), you have chosen a location yourself. You can use the Windows Explorer search function (if you really don't have a clue) for the file name, if you know it.

Answer (score 3):

When you choose to Open a file rather than Save it, firefox saves the file in your temp directory. On Windows, you can press <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then type `%temp%` to open your temp directory.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Firefox there is a download icon **⭳** on the right side of the Firefox toolbar. When you have completed a download, the download icon changes its color from black to blue.

[image]

Click on the download arrow and it will display a list of completed downloads.

[image]

Select any downloaded file in the list by moving the mouse cursor over it, and that downloaded file will change color to show you that you have selected it. Right-click the downloaded file that you have selected and from the popup context menu select *Open Containing Folder* and a file browser window (Windows Explorer in Windows) will open at the folder where your downloaded file is located. You can also open the file browser to the location where the downloaded file is located by clicking the open folder  which is marked by the mouse cursor in the above screenshot.

Comment: +1 looking at his question, I figured an answer should be simple. I actually knew and would've known it was the down arrow but wouldn't have known looking at other answers. +1 'cos your picture is worth many words.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the mega.co.nz Firefox extension on Windows, it downloads the files to %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\

Answer (score 1):

If you are using most recent versions of Firefox, now MEGA downloaded files are treated as a "blob resource" (to purposely avoid writing files using HTML5, something Chrome did when MEGA launched).
Not sure if History might remember the "blob resource" address. However and from personal experience it either is a cached file or a link to an actual "process" that downloads the file as it should. Exiting Firefox does clear the "blob resource" link.

On older versions, probably a cached file, but that would also be deleted upon exit.

My recommendation: try re-downloading the file.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla & MEGA

I found all the cached files I've downloaded in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\`.

Comment: the question is about downloaded file location,not the cache of the firefox

Answer (score 1):

The default location would be:

```
C:\Users\<YourAccountName>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxx.default\indexedDB\https+++mega.co.nz
```

Substitute the appropriate value for the `xxxxx` part.

Answer (score 1):

Mega.co.nz downloads the files in a temporary folder named idb, This folder is located here:
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\frxzit8g.default\indexedDB\https+++mega.co.nz\idb

In this temporary folder the download creates a lot of small files.
1 MB size per file.

No idea, how to combine these all files.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the files, open a command prompt window then navigate to the folder where the files are located then use the command "copy /b file1 + file2 + ... + fileN combinedfile.ext" without quotes. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mega downloads the files in a temporary folder named idb,
This folder is located here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\frxzit8g.default\indexedDB\https+++mega.co.nz\idb
```

In this temporary folder the download creates a lot of small files, after download is finished, it locates the entire download file at the FireFox download file.

If the Mega downloads is interrupting or stopping for any reason, the temporary file is stuck and takes a lot of free space.

Answer (score 0):

```
\Users\nishant\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[something].default\indexedDB\https+++mega.co.nz\idb
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Your answer is vague and could be troublesome to understand for people with less experience with Windows and how the structure is build up. Could you elaborate a little to make your answer better?